# how to do jquery image infinite scroll loop manual

Tags: jquery, image, scroll

i wanna scroll images to vertical just like 
[vertical scroll with simplyscroll](http://logicbox.net/jquery/simplyscroll/vertical.html)

how can i do that with infinite loop

please help,

and thanks a lot

Comment: what about content ? loop or fetch more from somewhere ?

Comment: nope, it didn't fetch from anywhere just 4 or 5 images only...

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at JQuery Tools Scroll-able. Should solve our problem.

http://flowplayer.org/tools/scrollable/